# Cartesian to Polar coordinates resulting in NaN

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, three.js, polar-coordinates

So I am working on a 3-D scene where I need to convert to and from polar coordinates at will, and have written a function to help me convert. The problem is that it is resulting in a NaN for one of the angles pretty regularly. The function I am using is as follows:

```
toPolar: function(x,y,z){
    var sqrd = (x*x)+(y*y)+(z*z)
    var radius = Math.pow(sqrd,.5)
    var theta = Math.acos(z/radius)
    var phi = Math.asin(y/x)
    var toReturn={
        r:radius,
        t:theta,
        p:phi
    }
    return toReturn
}
```

Phi is what is returning NaN, and Although I though I figured out where it resulted in NaN it seems as though it is happening in certain points all throughout the scene

You can see the problem here:
http://cabbibo.com/sketches/audioSketch3/

Where in the upper left hand corner you see the polar and cartesian coordinates of the camera, and the last section of the polar coordinates (phi) will show up as NaN from time to time.

I assume its some sort of problem with my math, because I am not that good at it, but it seems like it might be a different issue, such as me not understanding how to use Math.asin ...

Thanks for your time, and let me know if there is any other information anybody needs!

Isaac

Comment: can x be zero? that would result in a division by zero on that line

Comment: asin is only defined from -1 to 1; it returns NaN whenever y > x or y < -x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're expecting phi to be like Azimuth (e.g. in the horizontal plane over, -pi -> pi) you should use atan2.

```
var phi = Math.atan2(y,x);
```

Comment: on this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system in the coordinate system conversion section it says to use atan(y,x) not atan square correct? or will that result in a phi between 0 and 2PI, not -PI and PI?

Comment: whether you are working in terms of [0,2*pi) or (-pi,pi] is usually just convention, any math code using your angles should not notice. The issue with atan is only defined over an [0,pi/2) interval, so you can get an angle but not know which "quadrant" you are in. Atan2 effectively does an atan and then resolves which quadrant the angle is in, (you can look at the signs of x & y to do this) in order to get a full angle. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Answer (score 1):

You don't want polar coordinates; you appear to want spherical coordinates.

Your equation for phi doesn't look right.  Check this out:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

Comment: Sorry, I meant spherical. Always forget to add that extra dimension...  The other commenter says to use atan2, but on that article is says to use atan, do you know which one of these is correct, or will it just define the range of phi?

Comment: They're overloaded versions of the same thing.  I'd prefer atan2 because it preserves the quadrant you want to be in properly.